# python read mat file datetime array

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I'm trying to read a mat file using python's scipy io library, specifically a struct that contains an array of datetimes but it's not getting the information from the array. How do I extract the information?(An example of a cell: 22-Jul-2017)

```
import scipy.io as sio
# create string value to mat file
matPath = 'data/2017_Pervious11_F5.mat'
# load the information in the file in a format that python can interpret
matfile = sio.loadmat(matPath)
# in order: for slab1 get date_time, rn, qh,qe,qg and sup
s1_dates = matfile['S1']['D']
```

Output:

```
s1_dates [ MatlabOpaque([ (b'', b'MCOS', b'datetime', array([[3707764736],[         2], [         1], [         1], [        12],[         2]], dtype=uint32))], dtype=[('s0', 'O'), ('s1', 'O'), ('s2', 'O'), ('arr', 'O')])]
```

Comment: Provide MATLAB code to generate the exact file you are trying to open.

Comment: Looking up `MatlabOpaque`, it looks like the `mat` file contains some MATLAB class/object that `loadmat` cannot translate into `numpy`.  Dates, unless given in some consistent string format, are not readily interchangeable across programming languages.  I wouldn't expect a Python `datetime` object to be usable in MATLAB.

Comment: here is the link to the mat file    https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_s-ZK-B0ITFTU5mS1UyblhuRkE

Answer (score 1):

One solution that worked for me was to convert all matrix entries to 'char' format (in MATLAB), and load the new .mat file using the 'scipy.io.loadmat'.